# Convert a Date to specified format moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date stored in variable like below

```
var date = moment(new Date()).valueOf();
```

I need to format it like below

> CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss]TZD
>
> The Time Zone Definition is mandatory and MUST be either UTC (denoted by addition of the character 'Z' to the end of the string) or some offset from UTC (denoted by addition of '[+|-]' and 'hh:mm' to the end of the string).

I have tried like below

```
var required = moment.utc(date).format('CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss]TZD')
```

But it is resulting like below

```
"CC14-06-03T07:59:15.sssT+00:003"
```

But the expected format examples are

```
UTC : 

1969-07-21T02:56:15Z

Houston time :

1969-07-20T21:56:15-05:00
```

Comment: Take a look at Moment.js's [formatting documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). There are a few characters in your formatting string that aren't recognized by Moment.js

Comment: I'm always puzzled by "CCYY". If *MM* means "two digit month number" and *DD* means "two digit day–number", then surely "four digit year" should be YYYY? CC seems to infer century, which isn't very good since "2014" is in the 21st century, and writing it as "2114" is bound to be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try with:

```
'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ'
```

Output:

```
2014-06-03T08:16:15+00:00
```

[moment.js format documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: He's using the [`format` function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), not the format parser parameter string, so if I'm gonna nitpick, you've got the wrong url there :P Still the right answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
new Date(moment('14/07/2022 14:27:50', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'))
```

Output:

```
2022-07-14T17:27:50.000Z
```